# C# Selenium Webdriver using PageObjects: Unable to locate object using FindsBy; Can find same object using FindElement

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have C# automation code that uses Selenium Webdriver to find an object. This code works (see below):

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("Cyber Liability_start")).Click();
```

Recently, our test group voted to move to a Page Object Framework.  I have now created a class that uses the Selenium PageObjects library. Below is the same object but in a Page Object Class.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "Cyber Liability_start")]
public IWebElement btnNGP { get; set; }

public void ClickNGP()
{
WaitForLoad();         
btnNGP.Click();
}
```

However, when I run my test using the page object class, I get a "no matching element" error. So, it looks like Selenium is not able to find the page object. Any suggestions on how to resolve appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because the entry for the Page in the app.config file differed from the Page Object Class Name.

Entry in app.config file was

```
<add name="PC_ProductsProgramsPage"
```

while the class name was PC_Products_ProgramsPage.cs

When I changed the entry in the app.config file to "PC_Products_ProgramsPage", the page object was successfully identified.

Thanks